# WPF DataTrigger/Setter with DateTime comparison

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm just wondering whether it's possible todo a DATETIME comparison with the WPF, ideally I'd like to colour my datagrid depending on it's relevance to the current date.  Red for past files, green for future.  Thanks for any help!

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="files_datagrid" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource filelist_provider}}"         
ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1"> 
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">    <Style.Triggers>        
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=[filedate]}" Value=">TODAY">            
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />      
        </DataTrigger>  
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're better off using a [Value Converter.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Something like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DateTime), typeof(Brush))]
public class DateTimeToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
    if (dateTime.Date < DateTime.Now)
      return Brushes.Red;
    if (dateTime.Date > DateTime.Now)
      return Brushes.Green;

    return Brushes.Black;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

You could move the colours to be parameters to make it more generic if you feel like it.

Then apply like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
  <Setter Property="Background" 
          Value="{Binding Path=fileDate, 
            Converter={StaticResource dateTimeToBrushConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

Where dateTimeToBrushConverter is created in your resources.